# How to search in List<string> items

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a List and it is filled with  strings like this:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
data.Add(itemType +  "," + itemStock + "," + itemPrice);
```

So basically there are 3 string variables that are comma separated.

Now I want to search in this list and delete items that are from a specific type. That is I need to search that which elements of my list view begin with desired "itemType".

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question in the title ("How to search..."), this returns an `IEnumerable<string>` with the desired items:

```
var itemsToRemove = data.Where(x => x.StartsWith(specificItemType + ","));
```

To answer the question in your question body, you can use [`List(T).RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) to remove the items:

```
data.RemoveAll(x => x.StartsWith(specificItemType + ","));
```

---

However, I would suggest that you rethink your data structure. Consider creating a class `Item`:

```
public class Item {
    public string Type { get; set; }    
    public int Stock { get; set; }    
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return itemType +  "," + itemStock + "," + itemPrice;
    }
}
```

Then add these data structures to your list:

```
List<Item> data = new List<Item>();
data.Add(new Item {Type = itemType, Stock = itemStock, Price = itemPrice});
```

Then you can search, read, reformat, etc. without having to resort to string manipulation:

```
data.RemoveAll(x => x.Type == specificItemType);
```

Comment: Wouldn't comma be necessary? `x.StartsWith(specificItemType+",")`

Comment: @Banthar: Thanks, very good point. Added. It can still create wrong results, though, if the item type contains a comma, which is why I recommend the "safe" solution.

Comment: Thanks for the better solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
var matches = data.Where(d => d.StartsWith(itemType));
```

You can also use [RemoveAll with a predicate condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
data.RemoveAll(d => d.StartsWith(itemType));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var typematch = data.Where(t => t.StartsWith(itemType)).ToList();
```

Will return you a list of strings that start with a specified type.

Answer (score 1):

Data setup

```
List<string> data = new List<string>(); 
data.Add("Type1" + "," + "A" + "," + "A");
data.Add("Type2" + "," + "B" + "," + "B");    
string typeToExclude = "Type2";
int typeIndex = 0;
```

---

Filtering itself

```
var items = data.Where(
                  x => x.Split(new char[] {','})[typeIndex] != typeToExclude);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete them from the list so...

```
data.RemoveAll(x => x.StartsWith(itemType));
```